# How to match values in column A with values in columns B, C or D and return the name of the column where the match was found?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a table that looks something like this (but thousands of rows):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | a3 | a1 | a4 |
| a2 |  | a2 | a5 |
| a3 |  |  |  |
| a4 |  |  |  |
| a5 |  |  |  |

The idea is to end up adding another column, E, which tells me which "category" (B, C, and D being the different categories) each element of A is in.

In my mind, I'd want it to search B:D for all values of A, and then when it finds a match return the name of the column where the match was found.

Unfortunately, I'm not used to using Excel (I usually use R) and a bit out of my element. Any help would be much appreciated!

The desired output would be something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | a3 | a1 | a4 | "C" |
| a2 |  | a2 | a5 | "C" |
| a3 |  |  |  | "B" |
| a4 |  |  |  | "D" |
| a5 |  |  |  | "D" |

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

Refer the below screenshot.

[image]

In E1 the formula is.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF($B$1:$D$5=A1,COLUMN($B$1:$D$5),0)),4),1,"")
```

Note that after you write this formula you must convert this to an Array Formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar. The formula will be automatically enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

It will not work correctly without this step.

Drag it down up to the intended rows.

You may also use IFERROR to eliminate any #VALUE or #N/A error and replace it with blank when value is not found if at all the case be.

Depending upon the list separator character which may be ; instead of , in some regions, you may need to replace comma with semicolon in the formula, just in case.

In case you wish double quotes around the column letter.

```
=""""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF($B$1:$D$5=A1,COLUMN($B$1:$D$5),0)),4),1,"")&""""
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I took a vertical approach to the column header problem.  With a reasonable number of columns it works and the logic is pretty clear.
With this named Table2
[image]

I opened this up with whitespace for clarity and to point out a couple things.  The formula in cell E2 (again NOT part of the table) is:
[image]

SEQUENCE gives us an array the shape of one table column.

I do not know why this works but SUBSTITUTE replaces 1 (a number) in the array created by SEQUENCE with the table header as shown.  I found this by accident.  You can leave it blank, use "" or "1" or even "2" (which does not appear in any array) or "Donald" and so help me it works.
CHOOSE does the equivalent of HSTACK and voila!

Begin original post:  I worked on this problem using dynamic arrays and =LET() for fun. First, turn the data into a table to simplify your syntax.
This solution works as long as your data does not go beyond column Z because of the way columnarray parses the cell address.
Note table syntax also exposes column headers so if you could stack that array you could get actual column headers into the final output, not just column letters.  Alas, there appears to be no solution in Excel yet to broadcast the 1d header array to the number of necessary rows.  I tried it manually using VSTACK 5 times and it actually worked, but can't be built in shorthand.  Recursive lambda?

Formula in E2 (and make sure column E is not in the table):
[image: my formula]

Feel free to improve upon, especially the TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN...  Allowing LET to return IF(boolarray, columnarray, "") visualizes the 2d array that must be collapsed into 1d for the final output so you can see what you're working with.  Putting it out there for comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility of more than one occurrence, try something like:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(SORT(ADDRESS(1,($A2=B2:D6)*COLUMN(B2:D6),4)),""),"1",""))
```

which also sorts the columns.

If you have something other than literal letter labels that match the Excel column labels, the following will collect them all. `SORT` can be used to either sort by column order, or to alphabetize the actual header results:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IFERROR(SWITCH(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(SORT(ADDRESS(1,($A2=B2:D6)*COLUMN(B2:D6),4)),""),"1",""),"B",B1,"C",C1,"D",D1),""))
```